# Button doesn't appear after while cycle even though it works if i put it before cycle

Tags: php

I have my footer.php with admin button in it and when i include it at the end of my page the button doesn't appear.. But if i put it before this code:

```
<?php if ($row["rights"]=="2"):?>
<div id='cssmenu-admin'>
<ul>
<li name='admin' class='active'><a href='administration.php'><span>Admin</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

from footer.php before while cycle it works like it should.

This my footer.php file:

```
<div id="footer">
<hr>Copyrighted (C) 2014 by djdanas@gmail.com<br>
<?php if ($row["rights"]=="2"):?>
<div id='cssmenu-admin'>
<ul>
<li name='admin' class='active'><a href='administration.php'><span>Admin</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<br><hr>
```

And this is my page file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Pagrindinis</title>
<link href="CSS/stilius.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="CSS/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>

<?php require("includes/validate.php");?>
<?php require("includes/stilius.php");?>

<?php
require("includes/connection_to_db.php");

$sql = "SELECT prekės.* , CONCAT(vartotojai.name) as v_name
    FROM prekės 
    LEFT JOIN vartotojai
    ON vartotojai.V_ID=prekės.V_ID
    ORDER BY prekės.date 
    DESC LIMIT 8";
    $result = mysql_query("$sql");
?>

<?php mysql_close(); ?>

<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) : ?>
    <?php $image = '<td><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'" name="pix" width="270" height="200"/></td>' ?>
    <table class="two">
    <th><?php echo $row['name'] ?></th>
    <th>Prekės savininkas: <?php echo $row['v_name']?></th>
            <th><input type="button" value="Mainyti"></th>
            <tr>
            <?php echo $image?>
            <td><textarea disabled style="resize:none; background-color:white" name="about" rows="12" cols="65"><?php echo $row['specs']?></textarea><td>   
    </table>
<?php endwhile; ?>  

<?php require("includes/footer.php");?>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, i solved my problem by adding new variable

```
$rights = $row['rights'];
```

right after

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Pagrindinis</title>
<link href="CSS/stilius.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="CSS/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>

<?php require("includes/validate.php");?>
<?php require("includes/stilius.php");?>
```

in my page file and changed 1 line in my footer.php file from

```
<?php if ($row['rights']=="2"):?>
```

to

```
<?php if ($rights="2"):?>
```

now it's working like a charm :)

Comment: You’re creating invalid HTML here, and as long as you are doing that you can’t expect proper results. `table` can not have `th` as children, and you are opening `tr`s but never closing them. (And most likely you are creating nice XSS vulnerabilities as well.)

Comment: @CBroe `<tr>`'s closing tag is optional.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab in the dark here and say that your test

```
if ($row["rights"]=="2")
```

means you are checking to see if the user logged in has the "rights" of 2?

Then when you loop through your query...

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

You are overwriting your **$row** variable. So whatever you thought was in there to begin with, isn't anymore. You should use a different variable for either your user or looping through the query.

**EDIT**:
It's also possible that the variable isn't in scope once you get to where you are testing it. You could try using a print_r($row) in footer.php to see what is currently inside of $row -- that should help.

Comment: Can it be?  I think i don't overwrite it cause rights is stored in vartotojai table and i only take V_ID and name from this table